# \includesvg works, scaling does not

Tags: svg

in my document i got:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\def\svgscale{0.5}
\includesvg[svgpath = pictures/]{somefile}
\caption{svg image}
\end{figure}
```

Which does indeed import the picture, but the pictures size does not change with values like 0.5 or 1.5.

with 0.5 i was expecting a reduction in widht and height of 50%. Is that wrong?

Comment: The documentation of package `svg` does not say anything about scaling. It supports options `width` and `height`.

Answer (score 12):

Youre right, this one works quite nice:

```
\includesvg[width = 200pt, svgpath = pictures/somepicture]
```

keeps the aspect ratio automatically.

Answer (score 5):

The following worked for me:

```
\includesvg[width=30pt]{images/logo.svg}
```

Comment: This answer almost identical to [one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/329022/224762) that has already been given.

Comment: Yea, except the one already given, didn't work for me. That's why I'm adding this here. The `[]`, `{}` is what made it work

Comment: The command `\includesvg[parameters]{svg filename}` works like `\includegrpahicx` where `[]` is for parameters and `{}` is for the filenmame. The filename is essential, it cannot work without it and @James Baker may just have omitted it just because it is not necessary for the answer. `svgpath` is just when your file is not in your current working directory.  The essential part of the answer is `\includesvg[width = value pt]` which basically is yours too.

Answer (score 1):

I used this and it works.

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{svg}
...
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\def\svgscale{0.9}
\includesvg[svgpath = folder/]{fileName.svg}
\end{figure}
```